# API response time slow when running Android device on WIFI

Tags: android, retrofit, android-wifi, response-time

We are currently building a custom Android app running on a small Android device.
The app makes API calls to a Node server, running on an Azure App service.

When we connect the device with an ethernet cable, the response time is pretty quick (around 1 second - the server does a lot of processing) and also consistent.
However, if we connect the same device to our office wifi, the response time suddenly fluctuates a lot (same request that took 1 second on cable can now take between 2 and 8 seconds).

The app is using Retrofit to handle network calls.

I cannot immediately see what the issue should be - the wifi itself is not slow when using it with a laptop and we are not making requests and responses with a lot of data. But something is affecting the response time greatly when running on wifi.

So, does anybody have any idea or proposal for some areas to look into?

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: @zero cool - Unfortunately not a useful solution. We came to the conclusion that it was an issue with the specific hardware (a small Android device with quite a slow CPU), as the problem does not seem to show itself to the same degree on a regular consumer tablet.